# Error with Webform GDPR Module

Tags: webform-civicrm, gdpr

On a Drupal 7.72 / CiviCRM 5.25.0 / Webform CiviCRM 5.23 / Webform GDPR 5.XX (fork fromhttps://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr), I'm getting this message in log:

```
Error : Class 'CRM_Gdpr_SLA_Utils' not found dans WebformGdpr::getDefaultUrls() (ligne 157 dans /var/www/drupal/web/sites/all/modules/webform_gdpr-5.x/includes/webform_gdpr.inc).
```

I compared with a clone site and even if everything seems set exactly the same way, I don't get this error.

I understand that it is looking for an URL for the Data Policy which is also set in the plug-in.

Has anybody already been confronted to this issue?

Comment: Check again that the GDPR CiviCRM extension is installed and enabled.  The error is from the Drupal `webform_gdpr` module trying to use a class provided by the GDPR extension.

Comment: ok, I'll check once again.